# mysql_exceptions.OperationalError | _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: mysql, database, flask

I am using in linux system. Just can't able to solve the problem.Meanwhile, I browsed and applied all of thread from stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your password is not correct, try connect with:

```
mysql -u root -p<YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE>
```

Or, use mysqlsafe and change your root password.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you entered passwords correctly. I sometimes have this issue when I enter a wrong password.